# Python script to remove unique elements from a list and print the list with repeated elements in proper order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have written a script to remove all unique elements from a list and print the list with only repeated elements:

Below are some examples how the output list for an input list should be

```
Input list1:
1,2,1,1,3,5,3,4,3,1,6,7,8,5

Output List1:
1,1,1,3,5,3,3,1,5

Input list2:
1,2,1,1,3,3,4,3,1,6,5

Output List2:
1,1,1,3,3,3,1

#! /bin/python

def remove_unique(*n):
    dict1={}
    list1=[]
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(n)):
            if n[i] == n[j]:
               dict1[j]=n[j]
               dict1[i]=n[i]
    for x in range(len(n)):
        if x in dict1.keys():
           list1.append(dict1[x])
    return list1

lst1=remove_unique(1,2,1,1,3,5,3,4,3,1,6,7,8,5)
for n in lst1:
    print(n, end=" ")
```

The script above works exactly as expected when tested with few smaller lists. However I want some ideas on how to optimize the script (both time and space complexities considered) for input lists with bigger lengths ( 50000 <=len(list) <= 50M )

Comment: Jean-François has given you an efficient solution to this problem, but for future reference, `x in dict1` is better than `x in dict1.keys()`. It's tolerable in Python 3, since `.keys()` returns a [View object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) on the dictionary, but in Python 2 it's bad because it has to scan the dict and create a list of the keys. And then it has to do a linear scan of the `.keys()` list to perform the `in` test. And constructing that list on _every_ iteration of the `for x in range(len(n)):` loop is _extremely_ inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your script has a number of issues:

- the classical `if x in dict1.keys()` => `if x in dict1` to be sure to use the dictionary check instead of linear
- no list comprehension: `append` in a loop, not as performant.
- `O(n^2)` complexity because of the double loop

My approach:

You could count your elements using `collections.Counter`, then filter out a new list using a list comprehension using a filter on the number of ocurrences:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = [1,2,1,1,3,5,3,4,3,1,6,7,8,5]

c = Counter(list1)
new_list1 = [k for k in list1 if c[k]>1]

print(new_list1)
```

result:

```
[1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 1, 5]
```

I may be wrong but, the complexity of this approach is (roughly) `O(n*log(n))` (linear scan of the list plus the hashing of the keys in the dictionary and the lookup in the list comprehension). So, it's good performance-wise.

Comment: Fabre :  Thanks for the explanatory answer